# How to export survey results to excel

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, survey

How to export survey results to excel? I created a survey and added some questions to it, and I want to export a summary to excel

```
Lists/Survey3/summary.aspx
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the **Graphical Summary View** `(Lists/Survey/summary.aspx)` in the Survey List doesn't have `Export to Spreadsheet` option!!!

[image]

The `Export to Spreadsheet` is **only** available in the `Overview`

---

## **Workaround**

To export **Graphical Summary View** to Excel:

- Open your Survey List via **Internet Explorer**.
- Right-click on any free space and select `Export To Excel` as shown below

[image]

**[Output]**

[image]

Comment: Thank. It help me too.......................................

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the view you are in, you should click on the Actions menu, and select Export to Excel. This is an OOTB feature.

[image]