# Is it possible to create report from several surveys?

Tags: survey, survey-list, reports, promoted-results

I have several surveys with its results and I would like to do one report and sum up all the results.
Is it possible to do that in SharePoint?

Answer (score 0):

**As OOTB,** there is no way to generate a report for multiple survey lists!

---

**Workaround**

- For each list, Export the Survey result to a **spreadsheet**.
- Merge the result in one excel file
- Perform the calculation that you need!

> **Note** the `Graphical Summary` View (Lists/Survey/summary.aspx) in the Survey List doesn't have Export to Spreadsheet option!!! Check how
>   to export the result to excel at
>   [How to export survey results to excel](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/231215/how-to-export-survey-results-to-excel)